# Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable idk whats the problem

Tags: javascript

i didnt find the solution of this situation i hav checked this code multiple times and didnt find any solution how to solve this on my own.
I have tried to figure it out and found a similar code and when i copied that code i had no errors. and I have checked the difference and there was none. but im still getting errors.....

```
class Calculator{
  constructor(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {  // special function //
    this.previousOperandTextElement= previousOperandTextElement           // variables //
    this.currentOperandTextElement= currentOperandTextElement
    this.clear()
  }
  clear() {
    this.currentOperand = ''
    this.previousOperand = ''
    this.operation = undefined 

  }

  delete() {
    this.chooseOperation = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0. -1)

  }
  
  appendNumber(number) {  
    if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return 
    this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.toString()                  // adding the numbers to the screen //

  }

  chooseOperation(operation) {
    if (this.currentOperand ===  '') return
    if (this.previousOperand !== '') {
     this.Compute()
    }
    this.operation = operation
    this.previousOperand = this.currentOperand
    this.currentOperand = '' 
  }

  Compute() {
    let computation 
    const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand)
    const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand)
    if(isNaN(prev) || isNan(current)) return
    switch (this.operation) {
     case '+': 
        computation = prev + current
        break
      case '-': 
        computation = prev - current
        break
      case '*': 
        computation = prev * current
        break
     case '÷': 
        computation = prev / current
        break
        default: 
        return
    }
    this.currentOperand = computation
    this.operation = undefined
    this.previousOperand = ''
  }

  getDisplayNumber(number) {
    const  stringNumber = number.toString()
    const  integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0])
    const  decimalDigits = stringNumber.split('.')[1]
    let integerDisplay
    if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
        integerDigits = ''
    } else {
        integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString('en' ,{
             maximumFractionDigits: 0 })
    }
    if(decimalDigits != null) {
        return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`
    } else {
        return integerDisplay
    }
  }

  updateDisplay() {
    this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = 
    this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentOperand)
    if (this.operation != null) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = 
     `${this.getDisplayNumber(this.previousOperand)} ${this.operation}`
    } else {
        this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = ''
    }
  }
}



const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]')
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]')
const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]')
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')

// making the variables to operate the calculator //

const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

operationButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

equalsButton.addEventListener('click', Button => {
calculator.Compute()
calculator.updateDisplay()
})

allClearButton.addEventListener('click', Button => {
    calculator.clear()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
    })

deleteButton.addEventListener('click', Button => {
        calculator.delete()
        calculator.updateDisplay()
        })
```

**if you can me help I will be appreciate**
i hope theres just a little mistake and not something big that will cause a trouble

Comment: The problem is just that - you're assigning to a constant variable. Change `integerDigits` to a non constant so you can assign to it more than once. Read about `const` declarations [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#description).

Answer (score -1):

you are declaring a constant variable

```
    const  integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0])
```

and then trying to update it `integerDigits = ''`

Do `let integerDigits = ..` instead for a variable that will be updated